# How to prove that $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$ where $f$ maps to an element in a set, is a bijection?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $X$ and $Y$ be disjoint finite sets, $|X|=n$ and $|Y|=m$, so that we have the following bijections:

$f:\mathbb{N}_n \rightarrow X$ and $g:\mathbb{N}_m \rightarrow Y$

I need to prove that $h:\mathbb{N}_{m+n}\rightarrow X \cup Y$ is a bijection where $h$ is:

$$h(i) = \left\{ \begin{align} f(i)&,& \text{ if }& 1\le i\le n \\
g(i-n)&,& \text{ if }& n+1\le i \le n+m\end{align} \right. $$

My attempt:

**$h$ is injective**

$i \le n \Rightarrow h(i)=f(i)$, so $h$ is injective since we are given that $f$ is injective too.

$n+1 \le i \le n+m \Rightarrow h(i)=g(i-n)$ so $h$ is injective since we are given that $g$ is injective too.

My text also mentions that I should use the fact that $X \cap Y = \emptyset$ to prove that $h$ is injective. I do know that this condition will ensure that each element in $\mathbb{N}_{m+n}$, the domain of $h$, is mapped to only one element in $X\cup Y$, the codomain of $h$, but I don't know how to incorporate this into my workings.

**h is surjective**

This is one is really difficult for me. I do know by definition of surjective, I need to show that:

$\forall x \in X\cup Y, \exists i \in \mathbb{N}_{m+n}, h(i)=x$

I don't know how to proceed further.

The main difficulty I have is that the functions $f$ and $g$ are not defined in terms of a formula (as in the past exercises I have done so far) so this is something new to me.

EDIT:

$\mathbb{N_i}=\{1,2,3,\dots,i\}$

Comment: Is $\mathbb{N}_i$ suppose to just be $\{1,2,3,\ldots,i\}$?

Comment: For this kind of exercise, you really need to stick to the definitions. Spell out explicitly what the definition of injectivity is -- you haven't proved that $h$ is injective.

Comment: You want to prove being injective or surjective just follow the definition.

Comment: @N.Owad Yes, it is

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Since $h$ is equal to $f$ or $g$ then $h$ is injective since $f$ and $g$ is injective since a bijection implies injection. This is not enough?

Comment: If the sets weren't disjoint it then $h$ wouldn't be injective. And yet you haven't used that hypothesis. Try to find the flaw in your proof.

Comment: Something to note for later: For finite sets you only need to prove one or the other if the sets have the same cardinality. Prove either injectivity or surjectivity and the other immediately follows. I think it's clear that $\mid X \cup Y \mid=\mid \Bbb{N}_{n+m} \mid$.

Comment: To injectivity, you need to show $h(i)=h(j)\implies i=j.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a **hint** though:

**Injectivity:**

suppose $h(i)=h(j)$ some $i$ and $j$.

then one of the following must be true

1. $f(i)=f(j), \quad i,j\leq n$
2. $g(i-n)=g(j-n) \quad i,j > n$
3. $f(i)=g(j-n) \quad i\leq n, \; j>n$
4. $g(i-n)=f(j) \quad i>n,\;j\leq n $

Now use what you know about $f,g$ and $X \cap Y$.

**Surjectivity:**

Here's a way, although you can probably find a better one (I'll edit if I think of one):

Number the elements of $X$ and $Y$ so $X=\{x_1, \ldots x_n\}$, and $Y=\{y_1, \ldots, y_m\}$ such that $f(i)=x_i$ and $g(j)=y_j$. That should work.

So think of a number such that $h(?)=x_k$ and another such that $h(?)=y_j$ some $k$ and $j$.

Comment: This is brilliant too.+1